# ERROR in ../../../../ Cannot find namespace 'Sizzle'

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, npm

Right after I did `npm install @types/jquery` i got this problem when compiling my Angular project with `ng serve`

```
ERROR in ../../../../../../AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/WebStorm2020.1/javascript/extLibs/global-types/node_modules/@types/jquery/misc.d.ts:27:33 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Sizzle'.

27     interface Selectors extends Sizzle.Selectors {
                                   ~~~~~~
../../../../../../AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/WebStorm2020.1/javascript/extLibs/global-types/node_modules/@types/jquery/misc.d.ts:3
5:14 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Sizzle'.

35         ':': Sizzle.Selectors.PseudoFunctions;
                ~~~~~~
../../../../../../AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/WebStorm2020.1/javascript/extLibs/global-types/node_modules/@types/jquery/misc.d.ts:4
3:17 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Sizzle'.

43         filter: Sizzle.Selectors.FilterFunctions;
                   ~~~~~~
../../../../../../AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/WebStorm2020.1/javascript/extLibs/global-types/node_modules/@types/jquery/misc.d.ts:6
643:23 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryStatic'.

6643 declare const jQuery: JQueryStatic;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../../AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/WebStorm2020.1/javascript/extLibs/global-types/node_modules/@types/jquery/misc.d.ts:6
644:18 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryStatic'.

6644 declare const $: JQueryStatic;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I re-cloned my project and put it in a separate Folder and when I launch I also get this

```
ERROR in error TS6053: File 'C:/Users/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/WebStorm2020.1/javascript/extLibs/global-types/node_modules/@types/jquery/misc.d.ts' not found.
```

Checked the folder misc.d.ts exist I don't understand what's going on .

[image: here]

Comment: Fixed it I delete     //"../../../../../../AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/WebStorm2020.1/javascript/extLibs/global-types/node_modules/@types/jquery/misc.d.ts" in tsconfig.app.json

Comment: Since you resolved this, I wanted to not: You've tagged this Angular and JQuery. If you are using both: don't.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename in tsconfig.json to
"../node_modules/@types/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.d.ts"